# Meteor Bootstrap node modules overwrite my own css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less, load-order

Im using **Meteor**
why node modules are load at last, and overwrite my own css files in `imports/` directories? 
Im using **bootstrap**, but there are `class`es that I don't like as `background-color` `body`. Here happens this:
in my directories:

```
import/ui/socially/socially.less  
body{ backgrond-color: #000000;}
```

but don't work, when the firefox or chrome refresh the same default bootstrap color always appear.

I read the documentation Order Loads but this no solution my issue. 
I don't wanna overwrite original files of the bootstrap, or delete, or edit because is not good idea when I will use `.git`
Any ideas?
Thanks for all. Please I have many days in this issue jajaja

Comment: if your CSS really says `;` you could try changing it to `:` - oh and add the missing `u` in `background`

Comment: - Hello @CupawnTae : The syntax its ok (I wrote bad in this post jejeje) sorry for that! and thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your css syntax

`body{ 
    background-color: #000000
 }`

- Make sure you load your external CSS file after the bootstrap css file else your rules will get overwritten
- If it still doesn't work. Try this :

`body{ 
        background-color: #000000 !important
   }`

Comment: - Hello! the_lost_one. The syntax its ok (I wrote bad in this post jejeje) sorry for that!

Comment: -Hello! the_lost_one: !important works well !. Now, all mi class have !important at the end  of the statements., thank you very much! I would like give you a (+1)  but I can't because I dont have 15 of reputation. But Thanks for all.

Comment: Haha that's alright !! Just make sure you don't overuse !important. ( Code ends up looking ugly )

Comment: - Hello! @the_lost_one    : Yes, yes, the code is ugly now, because I use overuse !important. but No matter, it works for me. Meteor is strange, I am migrating to Meteor, I came from LoopBack,  strange is that only I am copy and paste some html and css and that worked perfectly fine before meteor. I think and I hope  that I really, really find the solution for this. But !important really outme to a big problem because i need finish my work in 4 days jajajaja